# Limit of area as function expands over full domain.

Tags: calculus, limits, area

In my calc class we’ve been working on definite integrals and area under a curve. I was wondering, if we let the lower and upper bounds approach the infinities, can you approximate or calculate how the area behaves?

Here is my rough sketch of the idea:

$$f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$$

$$\frac {d}{dx} f(x) = f’(x) \land f’(x): \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$$

$$a,b \in \Bbb R$$

$$\lim \limits_{(a,b) \to (-\infty, \infty)} \int_a^b f’(x) x’$$

$$= \lim \limits_{(a,b) \to (-\infty, \infty)} f(x)|_a^b$$

$$= \lim \limits_{(a,b) \to (-\infty, \infty)} [ f(b) - f(a) ]$$

$$=\lim \limits_{(a,b) \to (-\infty, \infty)} f(b)  - \lim \limits_{(a,b) \to (-\infty, \infty)} f(a) $$

Answer (score 1):

The very last line
may not be true
if f(a) and f(b) both diverge.

Comment: In which case the limit is undefined and probably increases to infinity, I presume?